# Netlogo - expected constant error

Tags: foreach, netlogo

I have this line of code:

```
set SSB sum [foreach  [foglie with [ipotetico? = false]] [((([media] of self ) - media-tot ) ^ 2) * ([larg] of self * [altez] of self)]]
```

- *foglie* are an agentlist;
- *media-tot* is a global variable

I cannot figure out why it gives me the error:

> expected constant

I found the following loophole but it looks to me not elegant and maybe even slower:

```
set SSB 0
ask foglie with [ipotetico? = false] [ set SSB (SSB + (( [media] of self - media-tot) ^ 2) * ([larg] of self * [altez] of self)) ]
```

- What do you think?
- How can i make the first code to work?
- Is the second code equivalent?

Comment: `[...] of self` adds no meaning and can always be omitted. instead of `[x] of self`, just write `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good question will include a *minimal* example of the problem.  In this case, in your first attempt above, it looks like you do not understand the difference between agentsets and lists, nor the use of `foreach`.  So you need to read about this.

- `sum` requires a list as input
- to make a list with the bracket notation, you need to include only constants; otherwise, use `list`
- putting an agentset in brackets does not produce a list, for the above reason, but even if you used `list` you would get a list containing the agentset as an element, not a list of the agents
- `foreach` does not return a list (but `map` does)

Assuming `media`, `larg`, and `altez` are foglie attributes and `media-tot` is a global, you could have done the following:

```
sum [(media - media-tot) ^ 2 * (larg * altez)] of (foglie with [ipotetico? = false])
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.
I apologize for not including a minimal example but the requirements changed and I have to show the model tomorrow.